# NSUnderlyingError = "bad URL"

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to return a JSON from Google, using the following method:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com.br/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", pointOrigem, pointDestino];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; 
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"%@", urlString);
```

As you can see, I've logged the url to make sure everything is ok. Here it is:

http://maps.google.com.br/maps/api/directions/json?origin=rua+cabral+983+Porto+Alegre+RS&destination=travessa+ouvidor+128+Porto+Alegre+RS&sensor=false

Someone know what is wrong with my code?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Somehow, the above works for me. Can you try using something like: `NSString *encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];`